# Swift3 loop dictionary to add value

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3

I m new to programming I just playing around in playground, I am trying to loop in a dictionary to do some calculation and add them into new dictionary however, I can only add one dictionary value back. I am not sure why. Can anymore tell me and point out the point?

```
    var name:String?

var popDict: [String: Array<Double>]?
var FinalDict: [String: Array<Double>]?
var mean: Double?
var elementSideArr: Array<Double>?

var nameArray = ["Olivia": [1,2,2,2,1,2,1,0.0001,0,1,2], "Amber": [52,52,65,66,57,63,62,0.0001,0,0,0]]

var doubleArr = [Double]()

for (key, value) in nameArray{

  let thisValue = value
  let arrayS = thisValue.prefix(7)
  let slice = arrayS[0...6]
  let popSideArr = Array(slice)
  let average: Double = (popSideArr as NSArray).value(forKeyPath: "@avg.self") as! Double

      mean = average
  let thatValue = value
  let arraySS = thatValue.suffix(3)
  let sslice = arraySS[8...10]
   elementSideArr = Array(sslice)


  elementSideArr?.insert(average, at: 0)


  let dict = ["\(key)":  elementSideArr!]

  for (key,value) in dict{

    popDict = dict

  }
}
print(popDict!)
```

["Olivia": [1.5714285714285714, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]] // It is the only output but it should be 2 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your inner for loop you are initializing whole new dictionary to `popDict` also you don't need for loop if you are having single key and value pair with your dictionary.

**Replace line of codes:**

```
let dict = ["\(key)":  elementSideArr!]
for (key,value) in dict{
    popDict = dict
}
```

**With:**

```
popDict["\(key)"] = elementSideArr!
```

**Note:** No need to cast swift array to NSArray to calculate `average` you can simply use `reduce` to get total and then divide the total with array count.

```
let array = popSideArr as? [Int] ?? []
let res = Double(array.reduce(0, +)) / Double(popSideArr.count)
```

Comment: I got some unwrapper problem after changing your code what should i change?

Comment: @kings077712 Your dictionary is optional so either change its declaration to `var popDict: [String: Array<Double>] = [:]` or changed line `popDict["\(key)"] = elementSideArr!` to `popDict?["\(key)"] = elementSideArr!`

Comment: @kings077712 Welcome mate, Also to get the avg no need to cast array to `NSArray` you can get the avg with swift array this way `let res = Double((popSideArr as? [Int] ?? []).reduce(0, +)) / Double(popSideArr.count)` You can even check my edited answer

Comment: Thanks! I just found how to do the average in other post

Comment: Can I ask you another question? I want to retrieve data from condition in dictionary is that possible? For example ``Olivia[2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0]
Amber[60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]``  I want to print the name(key) with value[0] = 60.0 is that possible?

Comment: @kings077712 Don't get your question but if you want to print the first object from array using key you can go this way `yourDic["Amber"][0]` If you expecting something else add new comment with more explanation

Comment: Okay I am learning how to use dictionary:D, now I want to check if there is any value[0] = 60 by loop the dict without access the key. Is that possible?

Comment: I saw this in git but don't know how to use it [link](https://gist.github.com/ijoshsmith/a411775b78f107f1c51152c6eda9d665#file-dictionary-keysforvalue-swift)

Comment: @kings077712 Ans you want key for the value[0] == 60? in this case Amber?

Comment: yes i have researched but I think it is kinda hard doing in ``[String:ArrayDouble]``

Comment: [it is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863262/swift-dictionary-get-the-value-without-access-or-knowing-the-key) of the new question please have a look