# Swift dictionary get the value without access or knowing the key

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am using the dictionary and trying to get the value without knowing or accessing the key.
It is my dictionary look like `"Olivia":[2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0],"Amber":[60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]` It is a `[String: ArrayDouble]` dictionary but I want to check if there is any value in the Value(ArrayDouble) which contain 60.0 then get display the Key for that value. What I was tried to do is :

```
let number = 60.0
for (key, value) in dict{

  if (number== value[0]){

    print(...the key)

  }else{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go like this.

```
let dic = ["Olivia":[2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0],"Amber":[60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
let filterKeys = dic.flatMap { $0.value.first == 60 ? $0.key : nil } 
//If you are having only one pair like that then simply access the first object from array
print(filterKeys.first)
//Other wise you can access the whole array
print(filterKeys)
```

**Note:** If you want to check that ArrayDouble contains specific value instead of just comparing first element you can try like this.

```
let filterKeys = dic.flatMap { $0.value.contains(60) ? $0.key : nil } 
//If you are having only one pair like that then simply access the first object from array
print(filterKeys.first)
//Other wise you can access the whole array
print(filterKeys)
```

**Edit:** If you want to check arrays contains object with `> 60` for that you can use [`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2297359-contains).

```
let filterKeys = dic.flatMap { $0.value.contains(where: { $0 > 60}) ? $0.key : nil }
```

Comment: What if I want to check other value? or making a condition like > 60 ?? is that possible?

Comment: @kings077712 You mean check any of value of array and check is it > 60 or not? Or just compare first object of array?

Comment: Yes and not just compare first object!

Comment: Sorry to make it more difficult and difficult but I want to as is that possible to check value[0] > 60 and value[1] > 5 ?

Comment: @kings077712 If you want to compare just this two?  you can compare it like `let filterKeys = dic.flatMap { ($0.value[0] == 60 && $0.value[1] > 5) ? $0.key : nil }` Is all that you want or any thing left?

Comment: so if there are more I just need to add an operator to make a condition? I can't think anymore haha Thank you so much I learnt a lot from you today:D

Answer (score 2):

You could also use **first(_ where:)**,

```
let item = dict.first { key, value in
  value.contains(60)
}

let key = item?.key // this is your key Amber
```

With this in place, you could create a predicate function which you could modify to suit your need,

```
let predicate = { (num: Double) -> Bool in
  num == 60.0
}

let dict = ["Olivia":[2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0],"Amber":[60.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]

let item = dict.first { key, value in
  value.contains(where: predicate)
}

item?.key
```

You could change the predicate as you require,

```
let predicate = {(num: Double) -> Bool in num > 60.0} // predicate to filter first key with values greater than 60.0

let predicate = {(num: Double) -> Bool in num < 60.0} // predicate to filter first key with values greater than 60.0
```

and  so on.